# Parsing huge XML in Ruby doesn't process full file in server

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, nokogiri

I need to parse a 3MB XML file using Nokogiri and Httparty to parse content from the links in the XML.

It works fine when I do it on my Windows 7 PC but when I run the same script in a VPS, it doesn't seem to process it fully.

Is it because of the limit on the maximum execution time of a Ruby script on the server? If so, how can I increase that in Ubuntu?

Comment: 3Mb doesn't sound that big. How does it fail?

Comment: @FrederickCheung there are over 3000 records in that xml file but it only saves 27 records out of those in database, even if we consider half of those returned errors there should be a lot more saved. What it does it calls the amazon product advertising api for each of those records. maybe the API limit could be a reason but not too sure.

Comment: 3MB isn't big. 3GB would be big. Without code it's really hard to tell what's going on, and since it's on a VPS where the problem occurs but works on Windows, the question doesn't sound like it's Ruby or Nokogiri related, but tied to the system, making it sound very much like it's off-topic for Stack Overflow. [su] might be a better choice.

Comment: Hello @theTinMan thanks. I figured out it was due to amazon posing API call limits so i just used a 1 second sleep on each iteration and it seems to be working now. It was working on my local PC because the speed isn't as fast as the server's so the requests to amazon api were made at a slower pace .

Answer (score 2):

Noone will tell you exactly why it happens without logs. Did you browse them?

As far as VPS and xml are concerned - you may exceed the maximum available memory on the server (what will happen quickly if you have multiple clients, all of them loading xmls). I'm not sure how you are using Nokogiri, but my advise is to check whether you're using SAX parser (http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/SAX/Parser)

Eventually you will use less resources (memory, execution time) but there is a drawback - SAX parsers are much harder to write, especially when xml structure is  complicated, but it may be wort (look for benchmarks "Nokogiri DOM vs SAX")

Comment: thanks for the reply. I agree but only the admin ie myself is the one who runs that script maybe like once a day. I had tried using another gem called Ox for parsing but it seemed a bit harder to use so eventually went with Nokogiri. Where should i check the log files btw? Could you point out where they are saved in Ubuntu(I am new to linux and primarily use windows)? This has nothing to do with the server otherwise I could have checked the server logs.

Comment: ok, but you should have access to logs anyway, otherwise one day you encounter a problem you won't be able to resolve without them. 
even if don't have access to them you should ask whether he may sync them to machine you have access to

Comment: actually i myself built it :) but am new to the ubuntu and linux stuff, but had to use it on the server. I will try to set logs for those thanks.

Comment: yes, Ox is a bit harder but the fastest one. 

logs - it depends on how the application is rub. If it's Rails then by default logs are written to withing application log folder. If you have normal ruby program (you run it via command like `ruby program.rb`), then everything (puts, etc) goes to standard output. Read more about standard output/input - it applies to all linux processes, not only the ruby ones.